# Graph Theory Question: Show that, in any group of 2 or more people, there are always 2 with exactly the same number of friends inside the group.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Show that, in any group of 2 or more people, there are always 2 with exactly the same number of friends inside the group.

So, intuitively, this makes perfect sense, but I am having some trouble getting it down on paper. Could someone help me get started please?

Answer (score 7):

You have to assume friendship is symmetric.  If there are $n$ people, there are $n$ possible numbers of friends, from $0$ through $n-1$.  If there are not two people with the same number of friends, each of these must occur once.  Consider the people who have $0$ and $n-1$ friends-are they friends?

Comment: Ok, I got it, thanks.

Comment: Nice answer, however how does this relate to graph theory. I got this question in a graph theory book too, but I assumed I should prove it graph-wise.

Comment: @Ross Millikan, are you trying to say that we should use the pigeon hole principle i.e., as the number of degrees available are from 1(as if they are friends they cannot have 0 relations) to n-1 and the number of vertices are n hence at least one degree must be repeated

Comment: @AnubhavPandey:  The number of degrees available is $n$, as you can have someone with no friends.  But if they all have a different number of friends, they all have to be used, so there will be someone with no friends and someone with $n-1$.  The contradiction comes because a person with $n-1$ friends is friends with everybody, which would include the person with no friends.

Answer (score 2):

We have $n$ people in group. One can have from $0$ to $n-1$ friends, if no 2 people have the same amount of friends, then **degree sequence** for such graph would look like this:

$(\underbrace{0,1,2,3}_{n-1\text{ numbers}},..,n-1)$

Now, according to score theorem, we can see that this graph can't exist, $n-1$ degree vertex can't be connected with $0$ degree vertex. There have to be two people with same amount of friends.

Answer (score 0):

According to Havel-Hakimi algorithm a degree sequence $$d=\{d_1,d_2,......,d_n\}$$ corresponds to a simple graph if and only if the list $$d'=\{d_2-1,d3-1,.....,d_{d_1+1}-1,d_{d_1+2},.....,d_n\}$$ is a sequence of non-negative integers and is graphic.

Here to prove the required statement, let all the degrees(number of friends) of all the nodes(persons) be different and the graph $G$ be simple initially; this is our assumption.Now we would try to contradict this statement.
Let the number of persons be $K$ then the degree sequence would be (in increasing order) as follows:-
$$d=\{k-1,k-2,.......,k-(k-1),0\}$$ now if we apply Havel-Hakimi algorithm,we delete the first node corresponding to $(k-1)^{th}$ degree and subtract $1$ from all the subsequent $k-1$ degrees, we see that $0$ becomes $-1$ ,which is negative so it is not a simple graph i.e. one person may be a friend two or more times to another or may be a self friend which is ridiculous and against the normal assumption in the question, 
This contradicts to our assumption that $G$ is simple, Hence proved that there must be at least two persons with exactly same number of friends.